# Javascript function not returning values

Tags: javascript, return-value

I'm trying to get the value for row and col with the following function:

```
function find_winning_position(value, row, col) {
    var i, j, chcount, emptycol, emptyrow;

    chcount = 0;
    emptycol = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (document.getElementById(elementArray[i][j]).innerHTML == value) {
                chcount++;
            }
            else if (document.getElementById(elementArray[i][j]).innerHTML.length == 0) {
                emptycol = j;
            }
        }

        if (chcount == 2 && emptycol != -1) {
            row = i;
            col = emptycol;
            return row;
            return col;
        }
    }
}​
```

how to get it? what am doing wrong here... can anyone explain?

```
var row = -1,
    col = -1;
find_winning_position("O", row, col);
alert("row value" + row);
alert("col value" + col);
if (row != -1 && col != -1) {
    //do some thing here
}​
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you spend more time formatting your question next time please?

Comment: a function can return only one value.

Comment: @pranav : yeah i tried with only return; too

Comment: Is `if (chcount == 2 && emptycol != -1) {` true? Put a breakpoint in and check. You don't have any returns except inside this block.

Comment: @asawyer : i checked.. then only i posted this question here...

Comment: @Sriram90 Ok, does it enter the `if(...)` block or not then? Also, See my edit in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that you are trying to `return` when you have already `return`ed.

The second problem is that you don't assign the return value of the function to anything.

```
return { "row": row, "col": col };
```

and

```
var position = find_winning_position("O", row, col);
row = position.row;
col = position.col;
```

You also need to cope with the situation where the function doesn't return anything (since all your returns are inside an if statement).

Comment: if i use like this row = position.row;
col = position.col;, am getting error like this, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined

Comment: @Sriram90 — I refer you back to the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. you can only return one value... this does not make sense:

   return row;
   return col;
2. your usage example actually does not expect returned values, it expects the function to change the values it created in the global scope.
3. the function actually does not change global values because it is being passed variables with same names and works with the local ones.

what you can do:

a. do not pass `row` and `col` to the function, and instead it will work with global variables. and then no need to return anything from it.

b. return an object with two properties...

```
return { row: row, col: col };
```

Comment: option _b_ is what @Quentin suggested, too - more details on it in his reply.

Answer (score 1):

Execution ends when you reach a return, so the second return is unreachable.

```
return row;
return col; // will never hit this line
```

To return both, I'd probably wrap them together like this:

```
return {
    Row: row,
    Col: col
};
```

You also don't have a return statement to return anything if that `if(...)` block doesn't evaluate to true, that could be why your not seeing anything back at all.

**edit -** your call site ignores returned values, and you are depending on mutating the arguments. While it may or may not work, it's a practice I try very hard to avoid without explicitly saying in the function name that the function will be mutating the state at the call site.

I would change the function to return an object like this:

```
return {
    Row: i,
    Col: emptycol
};
```

And change the call site to this:

```
var row = -1,
    col = -1;
var result = find_winning_position("O", row, col);
alert("row value" + result.Row);
alert("col value" + result.Col);
if (result.Row != -1 && result.Col != -1) {
    //do some thing here
}​
```

Comment: @Sriram90 and as Quentin also told you, and I tried to hint at in comments already, you are not returning anything if your `if(..)` block is not hit. Consider adding a default return value, and checking for that condition at the calling site.

Comment: i got your point, if it doesn't enter the loop the row & col value should be -1, because we declared it earlier.

Comment: @Sriram90 Except if you are now using our suggestion of returning a composite object instead of mutating the arguments, not returning anything means your are trying to read the `.Row` and `.Col` properties of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

SA function can return only one value :-
if you want to return row and col then you can simply concat both and return and on the other
side you can split that and get both values.

```
return row+"-"+col;
```

other end split it :-

```
var obj=find_winning_position("O", row, col);
var spl=obj.Split('-');
var newrow=spl[0];
var newcol=obj[1];
```

Comment: This is completely unnecessary and adds complexity to something that should be very simple.